# Why is my lens making a ticking sound?

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, sound

My Canon EF 50mm 1.8 lens is making a noise I never heard before. It takes pictures and focus as usual but produces a constant ticking noise when using live view.

I honestly have no idea what could be the problem. The noise only stops when I'm viewing the photos, when I remove the lens or when I'm not using the live view.
My other lens does not do this, so I'm 100% sure it's just this one.

Should I just ignore it ? I have no place to take it to get fixed.

Comment: Which camera? Is autofocus active the entire time you are in Live View? Which other lens? Most are a lot quieter than the EF 50mm f/1.8 II when focusing.

Comment: Canon t3.. I regularly have the AF active while I'm using live view.. I know it tends to be loud, but this ticking noise is constant & very odd. Its never done this before. It stops once i switch the AF off also. But i like to have it on, which is why i can't stand this noise.. & the other lens is just the one the camera comes with when purchased.. @MichaelClark

Answer (score 3):

The noise you are hearing is the lens being slightly refocused by the active AF while using Live View. The EF 50mmf/1.8 II is one of the noisiest lenses in the Canon lineup when focusing. You are hearing it every time it moves just a tad. If the noise really bothers you there are a few options to avoid it.

- Turn off active AF while in Live View (if possible with the T3). You will need to map a button to engage auto focus when desired. By default when in video mode most Canon models use the *AF ON* button if the camera has one, or the *AE Lock* (*) button if it does not. Depending on the T3's menu, you may be able to remap a button to perform the *AF ON* function while shooting stills in Live View.
- Turn AF off completely and use manual focus.
- Use a different lens. The EF 50mm f/1.4 is much quieter and also has a usable manual focus ring. The newer EF 50mm f/1.8 STM has also addressed both the usable manual focus ring and the noisy focus of the older lens.

Comment: Just to extend the third point, ALL lenses with the STM or USM designation should be very quiet.

Comment: Not necessarily. USM and STM lenses with IS can be pretty noisy due to IS, rather than the AF motor.

Comment: My one is doing the same and it is not on auto focus

Answer (score 2):

Turn off AF Mode AI SERVO - that fixed the problem for me. AI FOCUS and ONE SHOT (on a T3) both were noiseless, AI SERVO had the clicking sound.